# How to read all lines from notepad comma separated and updated specific column conditionally in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, foreach

how can we read all lines from notepad comma separated and updated specific column conditionally, its successfully iterating no error is coming but not to update the value in C#

```
string[] existingLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);    

foreach (var row in existingLines)
{                       
    row.Split(Text_Separator)[0] = "Test Data";
}

var newdata = existingLines;
```

Comment: You're updating the **result** of `row.Split(Text_Separator)[0]`, not `existingLines` or even the line in the `foreach` loop you're on.

Comment: i think row in only the variable to iterate the existing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a `for` loop to modify an item while iterating over it.  I believe you'll get an error if using `foreach`.  This is because you are exposing an enumerator which is read-only.

This will iterate through each row, modify a column and replace the current row.

```
string[] existingLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);    

foreach (var i = 0; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
{                       
    // retrieve row by index
    var row = existingLines[i];
    // split into array of columns
    var columns = row.Split(Text_Separator); 
    // update column
    columns[0] = "Test Data";
    // create row from array of columns
    var updatedRow = string.Join(Text_Separator, columns);
    // update row in array of rows
    existingLines[i] = updatedRow;
}

var newdata = existingLines;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` method will create a new instance of string array which is not referred to the `existingLines` variable. Hence, updating the value returned from `Split` does not reflect on `existingLines`

```
String[] stringArray = splitStrings;
if( arrIndex!= maxItems) { 
    stringArray = new String[arrIndex];
    for( int j = 0; j < arrIndex; j++) {
        stringArray[j] = splitStrings[j];
    }   
}
return stringArray;
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs